# TabBarController does not hide the subviews in its view when it hides bottom bar on push

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am trying to make an app that is based on a TabBarController which has a custom button in the middle of the tabbar that is like the one in Instagram and other apps alike.

The reason I know it will be a custom button is that when user presses the button he/she should not expect a 'view controllers' segue behavior but a presented view controller. As to my research by far,  it is hard to customize a tab bar item to do anything other than switching to another view controllers owned by the tab bar.

Assuming I was right about the button having to be custom (if you know how to add a bar button item onto a tab bar and has it present a vc instead of switching to a vc, please also include it in your answer), I added a custom button to the view of the tab bar controller:

```
- (void)addPostButton {
button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 55, 55);   
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"post.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:32.0/255.0 green:35.0/255.0 blue:44.0/255.0 alpha:1]];
[button.layer setCornerRadius:button.frame.size.height / 2];
[button.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
[button.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];


[button addTarget:self action:@selector(addPost) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


CGFloat heightDifference = 60 - self.tabBar.frame.size.height;
if (heightDifference < 0)
    button.center = self.tabBar.center;
else
{
    CGPoint center = self.tabBar.center;
    center.y = center.y - heightDifference/2.0-5;
    button.center = center;
}

   [self.tabBar addSubview:button];

}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self addPostButton];
}
```

my storyboard is currently constructed as: --root--> tab bar controller --view controllers--> navigation controller --root--> view controller. Now I am trying to make the navigation controller push a view and would like to hide the tab bar in the pushed view. I checked 'hides bottom bar on push', which worked fine, EXCEPT the added subview is still there.

Apparently, 'hidesBottomBarOnPush' only hides tabbarcontroller.tabbar but not other subviews tabbarcontroller.view holds.

I also tried adding the custom button to tabbarcontroller.tabbar but nothing shows up. So it seemed that I had to add the button to the its view, not its tab bar.And When I pop the vc I just pushed, the added button is beneath the tab bar instead of right above it. Something wrong with the tabbarcontroller's view hierarchy.

If you know any solution to either add a custom button to tabbarcontroller.tabbar, or, hide the tabbarcontroller.view's subviews in an elegant way, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Is this class the tab bar controller's class in storyboard?  Or just its delegate?

Comment: @nhgrif it is a subclass of tab bar controller, not its delegate.

Comment: I mean in the storyboard, did you assign THIS class to be the class that the tab bar controller is using?

Comment: yes, I did. [self.view addSubview:customButton] is working. Problem is customButton is not dismissed when vc is pushed, though the tab bar is. @nhgrif

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @SahilKapoor Did you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

This likely is happening because you've added the subview to the tab bar controller, not the tab bar itself. There are several ways to address this depending on how you've added the button.

Comment: I'm currently trying to set up something similar and I haven't figured out how to add the subview to the tab bar itself. It only shows up if I add it to the tab bar controller. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Check the runtime frames via capturing the user interface and see if the view is in the stack. You may have to create a custom subclass of UITabBar and do some programming.

Another possible solution is kind of a hack but would work. Add the view to tab bar, and in the viewWillAppear of whatever, write an extension for UIViewController that will traverse your view hierarchy and look for the tag of your custom button + remove it. Then, do the same for viewWillDisappear to readd it to your tab bar / have a function on your tab bar to readd you can call via a delegate.